# How to check EP page caller on AX client

Tags: axapta, x++, dimension, financial, enterprise-portal

I have added Financial dimension tab on enterprise portal lead's detail page. The web-part is controlled by AX class DimensionDefaultingEPController.
I need to make only one attribute of the dimension visible. How do I achieve this ?

As per my approach, I have find the web menu item of corresponding web-menu and tried to search that if its possible to check the web menu item as a caller. But didn't find a way to achieve this too. Please help.....

Regards,
Rishi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the caller is not a good idea anyway.

Better is to check the `element.args` parameters. 
You could sniff the `parmEnum` property value provided by the menu item. 
Supply different menu items for each different context.